# скрипт, выдающий только те слова, которые есть и в первом и во втором поле ввода (PHP)

Tags: php

Добрый день! Подскажите, как можно вывести слова, которые встречаются в двух полях ввода?
Сделала просто выдачу слов из полей ввода, а нужно вывести только одинаковые слова

```
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="textarea" name="one"/><br>
<input type="textarea" name="two" /><br>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Передать"><br>

</form> 

<?php
$a = $_POST['one']; 
$b = $_POST['two'];

echo  $a.'<br>';
echo  $b;

?>
```

Comment: 1. Разбейте $a и $b на слова (то есть получите два массива слов) 2. В цикле пройдитесь по первому массиву и проверьте наличии текущего слова во втором массиве. Для найденных слов делайте вывод. P.S. Сравнение массивов можно сделать одной функцией. Описание функций работы с массивами  есть тут http://php.net/manual/ru/book.array.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$a = $_POST['one']; 
$b = $_POST['two'];

$newArray = array_intersect(explode(" ", $a), explode(" ", $b));

foreach($newArray as $item) {
    echo $item.'<br>';
}
```